# Hidden field value updated but not showing updated value in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am setting the hidden filed value through JavaScript as below

```
 <script lang="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function ChangeVal()
 {
   var elem = document.getElementById("btnDownloadStream");
   if (elem.value == "Start")
   {
     elem.value = "Stop";
     document.getElementById('myHiddenInput').value = "1";
   }
   else
   {
     document.getElementById('myHiddenInput').value = "0";
     elem.value = "Start";
   }
 }
```

I am trying to get hidden field value in code behind. My code is

```
HiddenField myHiddenInput = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("myHiddenInput");
var val = myHiddenInput.Value;
```

Before this line I am calling one function which creates and generates the `GetResponseStream()`. While doing this I am not able to get the value from server controls. Why?

Comment: `Before this line i am calling one function which creates and generates the GetResponseStream().` : so you're saying if you **don't** do that it works?

Comment: Yes Michael

If i don't call the GetResponseStream() method then i am able to view the updated value.

Comment: Okay, well then including that code in the question is probably pretty important.

Comment: Are you using an update pannel on your page?

Comment: Ya i am using update panel in the page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hidden field have `runat="server"` attribute..

Comment: My hidden filed is running at server side only like

<asp:HiddenField id="myHiddenInput" runat="server" />

I am able to see the updated value in UI. But in code behind its showing old value

Answer (score 0):

You forget about `ViewState`. If you change data in the hidden field using java script code the `ViewState` do not get this changes and that's why you cannot get the correct value in code behind.

Comment: Try disable ViewState on the page.
You can add this in web.config

  <system.web>
<pages enableViewState="false" />

Also I recommend you this article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

There is also description of Disabling the View State.

Answer (score 0):

Set **Runat="server"** attribute to your hidden field as shown below :

```
 <input type="hidden" value="" id="myHiddenInput" runat="server" />
```

Then update your javascript function as shown below :

```
function ChangeVal() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("btnDownloadStream");
            if (elem.value == "Start") {
                elem.value = "Stop";
                document.getElementById('<%=myHiddenInput.ClientID%>').value = "1";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=myHiddenInput.ClientID%>').value = "0";
                elem.value = "Start";
            }
        }
```

now you can directly access your hidden field value in your code behind without using **Page.FindControl** as mentioned :

```
var val = this.myHiddenInput.Value;
```

**Update:**

One thing I have noticed that your button is server side button and in your javascript you call

```
var elem = document.getElementById("btnDownloadStream");
```

I think it should be

```
var elem = document.getElementById('<%=btnDownloadStream.ClientId%>')
```

otherwise you will always get the value of **else part**

Make sure this is not the case.

Comment: Yes i tried this method also.

My Code is

 

    protected void btnDownloadStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       var val = this.myHiddenInput.Value;
       if(val=="1")
       {
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
         HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();
         var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
         using (var fs = new FileStream(VideoPathFile, FileMode.Create))
         {
     //Code goes here
         }
       }
     }

Comment: No i am not getting any error. Simply its showing old value. When First time button clicked i am setting the value = 1, second time value = 0. But it still showing value = 1 in code behind, but in UI its showing value = 0

Comment: that javascript method is the only place where you set the value of the hiddenfield not from any other place right ?

Comment: ya.. that is the only place i am setting the value

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you make sure it whether this is the case or not.

Comment: I have tried this method also. This JS function is working fine. The value is updating because i am able to view updated value in my UI

Comment: Getting value is secondary thing. After click the button at second time any function is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase Changing the value in javascript will not affect the server side value.

if you want to change a server side value from javascript: You can try the following

```
// Javascript
var myHidden = document.getElementById("<%:myHiddenId.ClientId%>");
myHidden.value = myJSVariable;
```

Make sure the myHidden is a server control.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens in case you use the `UpdatePannel` in your page. if this is the case then place the `HiddenField` inside the `UpdatePannel` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

well @Vishweshwar Kapse is answered your question.

Place your hidden field in update panel and don't forget to add click event of button in trigger.